# Registering a 'click' event with google.maps.event.addlistener(autocomplete, ...)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like my program to do something following the event of a user clicking on a google maps autocomplete suggestion item - something along the lines of the following:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#input_field")[0], {});

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'click', function() {
    // do something
});
```

The common practice is to use 'place_changed' instead of 'click', but that's too general for my purposes, as it also captures the event of selecting an autocomplete box by scrolling over it with the up/down arrow keys.

I'd like to specifically capture the event that a user *clicks* (or presses, on a mobile device) a particular autocomplete suggestion. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you meant by "click", but the `click` UI event in Google Maps Javascript API means user clicks on the map view. A general use case for `click` UI event is to draw a marker on the map view, when user click(or touch/tap on mobile device) on the map view. You can refer to [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) for more information about Google Maps Javascript API UI Events.

So if you want to perform a place autocomplete when user clicks/taps on the map view, it will not be a really good user experience. In addition, you can not know the name(or text) of the place when your user clicks/taps on the map view.

Furthermore, the `place_changed` event means user clicks/taps/selects an item from the suggestion list. You can put a log statement inside your `place_changed` callback, and you will see the log will be printed when users clicks/taps/selects an item from the suggestion list. I am not sure why this does not give you what you need.

You can refer to these link for `place_changed` demo:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Or this JSFiddle link, it shows a popup dialog when you clicks/taps/selects an item from suggestion list:
https://jsfiddle.net/btc67xwp/

Comment: Indeed, you're right. There was something going on in my app which gave me the impression that the event was being triggered not only on click/taps, but also when the user scrolls through the autocomplete options with the up/down arrows. Thanks for the clarification.